# Scrollview not showing last item in layout

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

Here is the code that i'm facing the problem i took 2 linear layout inside scroll view now the last button inside 2nd linear layout is hidden or i can say not showing properly.

Here is the screen shot.
you can check that i selected area is button but not working properly.

[image]

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ConcernedPortionofScreen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/RestofScreen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.75"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="20dp">               

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_button_shape_with_bg_primary"
                android:minHeight="@dimen/minimum_height_all_object"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/add_child_rquest_margin_top"
                android:text="SELECT"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

when i try to remove layout_weight my layout getting mass.

[image]

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ConcernedPortionofScreen"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <!-- Parent FrameLayout 'FL' -->
                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <!--Conitans Tree Childs -->

                </FrameLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/RestofScreen"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.75"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="20dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:weightSum="1">

                    <!--Conitans Two Childs -->

                </LinearLayout>


                <EditText
                    style="@style/CustomEdittextTheme"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/add_child_rquest_margin_top"
                    android:hint="Enter Child Name"
                    android:minHeight="@dimen/add_child_rquest_minimum_height_all_object" />

                <EditText
                    style="@style/CustomEdittextTheme"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/add_child_rquest_margin_top"
                    android:hint="Select City"
                    android:minHeight="@dimen/add_child_rquest_minimum_height_all_object" />

                <TextView
                    style="@style/CustomEdittextTheme"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/add_child_rquest_margin_top"
                    android:hint="Select Birthdate"
                    android:minHeight="@dimen/add_child_rquest_minimum_height_all_object" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="1">

                    <!--Conitans Two Childs -->

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="1">

                    <!--Conitans Two Childs -->

                </LinearLayout>


                <EditText
                    style="@style/CustomEdittextTheme"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/add_child_rquest_margin_top"
                    android:hint="Enter Mobile Number"
                    android:minHeight="@dimen/add_child_rquest_minimum_height_all_object" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="1">

                    <!--Conitans Two Childs -->

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/add_child_rquest_margin_top"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/segoe_ui_bold"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="Note / Message :"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                <EditText
                    style="@style/CustomEdittextTheme"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/add_child_rquest_margin_top"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:lines="8"
                    android:maxLines="8"
                    android:minHeight="@dimen/add_child_rquest_minimum_height_all_object"
                    android:minLines="8"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical" />


                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/add_child_rquest_margin_top"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_button_shape_with_bg_primary"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/segoe_ui_bold"
                    android:minHeight="@dimen/add_child_rquest_minimum_height_all_object"
                    android:text="SUBMIT"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: what is android:minHeight="" dimention value ?

Comment: You are setting your LinearLayout height to `match_parent` so there will never be scrolling.

Comment: @SushilKumar its ' android:minHeight="40dp" '

Comment: @dharms scrolling working there are so many items on it but the last item having problem. I have same issue with other layout too.

Comment: you shouldn't use match parent on the child of scrollview and also remove the weights, these are the main problems.

Comment: @AsifRahman i took 2 Linear Layout inside scrollview that why i go for weights which manage relative my screen layout.

Comment: There is no use of weights inside scrollview here. Remove and test it.

Comment: @Raj but what if i want give fix part to all layout ?

Comment: @Raj checkout after removing weights my layout getting mess.

Comment: @dharms right sir

Answer (score 0):

This Happends Because of `layout_height="match_parent"` for ScrollView child LinearLayout
Change `layout_height` to `wrap_content`

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        //android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

    //childs ..........
    </LinearLayout>
<ScrollView>
```

**`wrap_content`**

Setting a View's size to wrap_content will force it to expand only far enough to contain the values (or child controls) it contains. For controls -- like text boxes (TextView) or images (ImageView) -- this will wrap the text or image being shown. For layout elements it will resize the layout to fit the controls / layouts added as its children.

[Official Docs Says](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams)

- `FILL_PARENT` (renamed `MATCH_PARENT` in API Level 8 and higher), which means that the view wants to be as `big as its parent` (minus padding)
- `WRAP_CONTENT`, which means that the view wants to be just big `enough to enclose its content` (plus padding)

Comment: did you removed  `android:weightSum="1"`

Comment: @Kishan and replace all child of ScrollView with attr `android:layout_height="0dp" ` to `wrap_content` or `match_parent`

Comment: i have to use layout_height because without it i can't make my layout and i used frame layout also.

Comment: @Kishan did you removed android:weightSum="1"

Comment: i remove "weightSum=1" from 
ScrollView => LinearLayout = > LinearLayout [from here i remove] yeah it works but problem is my layout getting mess ....

Comment: you have teamViewer ?

Answer (score 0):

Use nested Scroll View, scroll view will truncate the last item in the layout

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

add padding from bottom and check.
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:layout_paddingBottom="10dp"

Answer (score -1):

The **simplest solution** is placing `ConstraintLayout` inside `ScrollView` like this

```
    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:overScrollMode="never">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:baselineAligned="false"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

<!--            your other views could be here-->
<!--            your other views could be here-->
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```